# ELF 32-bit LSB executable, MIPS, MIPS32 rel2 version 1 (SYSV),

Tags: c

a few days back I bought a few smart cameras from Alibaba, and out of curiosity I asked for their SDKs and they sent me that too, but now I am unable to use it on my computer due to different architecture

I am using **Ubuntu 22.04 64bit** and the SDK is **mips-gcc472-glibc216** and when i use `file output` i get

> output: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, MIPS, MIPS32 rel2 version 1 (SYSV),
> dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-uClibc.so.0, not stripped

I am not able to see the output of it

I would like to know how can I solve this issue

Comment: You need mips toolchain. Camera is rather using `none` ABI

Comment: @0___________ I think my GCC is 4.7 and there are none for that version

Comment: They are separate toolchains (compiler linker, libraries and tools)

Comment: @0___________ so that means i can download any latest version and it will work?, I am new to using GCC and linux